# ng-repeat inside ui-gmaps-window not rendering data from $http call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I'm using angular-ui-gmaps.

I have an ng-repeat inside an  which doesn't render the html after the $http request.

```
<ui-gmap-window id="info_window" show="show" coords="position" options="infoWindowOptions">
     <ui-gmaps-window>
         <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="item in items">...</li>
         </ul>
     </ui-gmaps-window>
</ui-gmaps-window>
```

The below is the event that triggers the opening on the window, which works.

```
    $scope.markerEvents = {
        "click": function (e) {
            $scope.selected = _.first(_.where($scope.items, { "id": e.model.id }));

            $scope.map.center = {
                "longitude": $scope.selected.longitude,
                "latitude": $scope.selected.latitude
            };

            $scope.position = {
                "longitude": $scope.selected.longitude,
                "latitude": $scope.selected.latitude
            };

            ItemService.feedback($scope.selected.id).then(function (response) {
                $scope.items= [1, 2, 3]; //Dummy data, just to show result isn't empty.

                //Show the window
                $scope.show = !$scope.show;
            });
        }
    };
```

So yeah, the info-window content is being rendered before the $http request returns I guess.

Anyone know solution?

Cheers

Comment: Try calling $scope.$apply() after your http request succeeded.

Comment: @Billy true but AngularJS promises execute in a digest. I'd be surprised if the promise resolved outside of one. Hopefully that's not what the problem is.

Comment: Yes @MathewFoscarini is correct, $apply() isn't the fix, thanks for the comment though.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/797

Comment: You are correct @MathewFoscarini, forgot about the digest.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `$scope.show` is initialized to false before the view is rendered, then explicitly set it to `true` when the data is loaded.

```
$scope.show = false;
$scope.markerEvents = {
    "click": function (e) {
            ....
            ItemService.feedback($scope.selected.id).then(function (response) {
                 ....
                 $scope.show = true;
            });
        });
    }
};
```

I don't know what `<ui-gmap-window>` is, but it might not handle dynamic changes in the DOM. So wrap it in a `ng-if` to ensure it's only created when the data is loaded.

```
<div ng-if="show">
    <ui-gmap-window id="info_window" coords="position" options="infoWindowOptions">
        <ui-gmaps-window>
           <ul>
               <li ng-repeat="item in items">...</li>
            </ul>
        </ui-gmaps-window>
    </ui-gmaps-window>
</div>
```

Comment: I did try the ng-if around the element earlier without any luck. Tried again, still nothing. The ui-gmap-window is a module from the Angular.UI team (google map directives). 

I think the window directive doesn't handle dynamic changes. Trying to call setContent(), but can't seem to access native google infoWindow functions (due to it being a directive I assume). 

Cheers for the response

Comment: @Lee2808 I think that's the issue. Based on this: https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/823